# EXEs not recognized as executables on Win10?

Tags: git, exe

Recently installed Github Desktop and it wants to find git.exe on the path. I have Git installed in C:/PortableGit. I added C:/PortableGit/bin to my System path. I verified it's there. If I open a CMD window window and type "git" I get *'git' is not recognized as in internal or external command*. If I navigate in the CMD window to c:/PortableGit/bin and type "git" I get the same error. Works if I type "git.exe".

How is this happening? Has my system been messed up such that EXE is no longer recognized? Wouldn't other things be badly broken if this were true?

Note: Tried other versions of Git in other locations, same result.

Comment: wouldn't this be something to ask on superuser, not on stackoverflow? sounds like windows usage question

Answer (score 0):

I had a user PATHEXT with .RB. I deleted that. Seems to have fixed the problem.